# Windows XP computer reboots at start

Tags: windows-xp, crash, reboot

I have trouble with a Windows XP computer. After Windows is started and I can see the desktop background (sometimes I can use the system a few seconds), then the system is rebooted before I can do anything.

I have used a Windows XP CD and runned `chkdsk /r` from the repair console. But it didn't help. I have also tried booting in "safe mode" but it didn't help.

The `C:\Windows\Minidump` directory is empty.

What can I do to solve this?

**UPDATE:** I have now placed the harddrive in another computer and I have access to all data. Except from copying all data, is there anything I can make with the system so I can boot from the harddrive again? Is it "safe" to install windows on the same disk and directory - so I can access the data but not run the applications?

Comment: Before any serious answers can be made: Have you made changes to your system setup (drivers, new hardware, new a/v software, something like that) recently? I assume you get a "Windows did not shut down properly" at booting which gives you booting options - does it work with "Last known good configuration" or "safe mode")?

Comment: This is most certainly due to a faulty driver or software you recently installed. Windows will [store crash dumps](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315263) under `C:\Windows\Minidump` - maybe you can try to get one of them, using a Linux Live CD or something. Then you can try to analyze what caused the crash. This method worked for me once.

Comment: @Tobias: Yes I get the "Windows did not shut down properly", and I have tried all alternatives, but none of them work. Now I tried to remove a WiFi PCI-card, but it didn't help. I don't know if something in the system has changed, it's not my computer. I'm trying to help a friend.

Comment: @slhck: I accessed the `C:\Windows\Minidump` directory from the repair console, but that directory is empty.

Comment: Oh, this is bad. If you were able to get into your System settings you would be able to [set that it stores minidumps](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307973).

Comment: Removing any non-essential hardware should be the first step - if there is any left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get this computer booting with these disks. So I placed the disks in another computer and recovered all data.

Answer (score 1):

What is probably happening is that a service is failing to start and is set to reboot on either the second or third failure. Boot into safe mode, F8 before the windows loading screen, check your event viewer for errors to find the service that is failing. Open a run prompt and type in "services.msc" right click the service and go to properties on the recover tab make sure none of the failure actions are set to reboot the PC:

[image]

Comment: There isn't enough of time when the system has started, so I can't check the event viewer or even start the control panel.

Comment: @Jonas even in safe mode? I did not see you say anything about not being about to get into safe mode. You can get the mini dumps by plugging the drive into another PC.

Comment: Yes, even in safe mode. And the Minidump directory is empty.

Comment: @Jonas you should probably add that to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, Some time you can also solve this problem by starting Windows XP in safemode the again start it in normal with best working settings that options can be found by pressing F8 key before XP logo.